# Pronounceable Name Generator

Tags: c#

I'm learning C# and have written a function which generates an easily-pronounceable fictional name by alternating between taking one vowel and one consonant. The one parameter, `halfLength`, will be the amount of vowels added and the amount of consonants added, meaning that the length of the returned `string` is double the given `halfLength`.

```
static string GeneratePronounceableName(int halfLength)
{
    char[] vowels = "aeiou".ToCharArray();
    char[] consonants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz".ToCharArray();
    List<char> chosenVowels = new List<char>();
    List<char> chosenConsonants = new List<char>();

    Random r = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < halfLength; i++)
    {
        chosenVowels.Add(vowels[r.Next(0, 5)]);
        chosenConsonants.Add(consonants[r.Next(0, 21)]);
    }

    return string.Join("", chosenConsonants.Zip(chosenVowels, (v, c) => v.ToString() + c.ToString()));
}
```

Is there a way this can be made shorter, more idiomatic or more efficient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> int halfLength
> ```

Don't make the user think to much when specifying parameters if this can be avoided. Calculate the target length and let the user specify the length he needs.

If the *name* should always have an even length then you could check if the given one is odd and if so then add 1.

```
length = length % 2 == 0 ? length : length + 1;
```

The loop just divides this by 2:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length / 2; i++)
```

I do this because I assumed a longer string is better then a short one so I add 1 to odd lengths but this is actually not necessary as C# will round the number to the next lower `int` when dividing. This means that `5 / 2 == 2` as far as `int` division is concerned. If you're ok with shorter strings then you don't need the line with `length + 1`

---

> ```
> char[] vowels = "aeiou".ToCharArray();
> char[] consonants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz".ToCharArray();
> ```

You don't need to `ToCharArray` these because strings are already arrays. You can just define two constants:

```
const string vowels = "aeiou";
const string consonants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz";
```

---

> ```
> List<char> chosenVowels = new List<char>();
> List<char> chosenConsonants = new List<char>();
> ```

You don't need two lists that you join later. You can use the `StringBuilder` and create the *name* right away.

---

> ```
> chosenVowels.Add(vowels[r.Next(0, 5)]);
> chosenConsonants.Add(consonants[r.Next(0, 21)]);
> ```

Don't use magic numbers. Use the constants you have to get the length:

---

> ```
> r.Next(0, 5)
> ```

You can use the overload that takes just the `maxValue`.

---

> ```
> v.ToString() + c.ToString()
> ```

When building *longer* strings with lot's of concatenations use specialized methods or objects. Concatenating strings with the `+` operator is the slowest possible way to create a string. The `StringBuilder` is such an object. Highly optimized for string creation.

---

With all those optimizations the final result could look like this:

```
static string GeneratePronounceableName(int length)
{
    const string vowels = "aeiou";
    const string consonants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz";

    var rnd = new Random();
    var name = new StringBuilder();

    length = length % 2 == 0 ? length : length + 1;

    for (var i = 0; i < length / 2; i++)
    {
        name
            .Append(vowels[rnd.Next(vowels.Length)])
            .Append(consonants[rnd.Next(consonants.Length)]);
    }

    return name.ToString();
}
```

---

Alternatively to the `StringBuilder` you could use in this example a `char[]` array and build the string yourself:

```
static string GeneratePronounceableName(int length)
{
    const string vowels = "aeiou";
    const string consonants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz";

    var rnd = new Random(); 

    length = length % 2 == 0 ? length : length + 1;

    var name = new char[length];

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i += 2)
    {
        name[i] = vowels[rnd.Next(vowels.Length)];
        name[i+1] = consonants[rnd.Next(consonants.Length)];
    }

    return new string(name);
}
```

Comment: You don't need to test and increment `length`.  Integer division rounds towards `0` in C#.

Comment: @JacobManaker I just thought that a longer string is better then a shorter. If the user says 5 he would get a 4 so I just add 1 if it's odd.

Comment: @t3chb0t: Why?  The OP hasn't expressed any preference for longer names.

Comment: @JacobManaker well, to me `halfLength` can be only of an even number as far as ints are considered so I just assumed I take the next higher one. Anyways it's really a tiny _issue_ (if at all) that can be adjusted anytime and in any way.

Comment: @t3chb0t: of course this is quibbling in the weeds.  Your answer is correct; I'm just trying to point out an alternate way to interpret the problem that leads to a slightly simpler solution.

Comment: @JacobManaker then it's ok - you need to make assuptions or otherwise you end up with 100+ lines of code that can adjust itself for any possible input. I'll metion the division thing in the answer...